# creating multiple repositories

Tags: svn, apache

```
CentOS 5.5
Subversion 1.4
httpd-2.2.3-43.el5.centos.3
```

I am trying to create multiple directories for each project under a project category.

For example, we have projects for web, dev, test, etc

So all web projects will have their own repositories and the same for dev, and test.

My structure is this:

```
/var/www/svn/repos/WEB/web_project1
/var/www/svn/repos/WEB/web_project2

/var/www/svn/repos/DEV/dev_project1
/var/www/svn/repos/DEV/dev_project2
```

*_project* will have their own repositories. i.e.

```
svnadmin create /var/www/svn/repos/WEB web_project1
```

However, the problem is in the subversion.conf file.

I have this: `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf`

```
<Location /repos>
    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    SVNParentPATH /var/www/svn/repos/WEB
    SVNParentPATH /var/www/svn/repos/DEV
</Location>
```

This will list the project under DEV, as its this line comes under WEB. However, if I change to the other way round:

```
<Location /repos>
    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    SVNParentPATH /var/www/svn/repos/DEV
    SVNParentPATH /var/www/svn/repos/WEB
</Location>
```

This will list all projects under WEB. However, I can have one or the other. But I can't have both.

I was thinking of having the Location as /repos/WEB but that will only show WEB as well.

Is there any way to have multiple categories like I have described?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved.

/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf

```
<Location /WEB>
   DAV svn
   SVNListParentPath on
   SVNParentPath /var/www/wsvn/repos/WEB
</Location>

<Location /DEV>
   DAV svn
   SVNListParentPath on
   SVNParentPath /var/www/wsvn/repos/DEV
</Location>
```